# Total no. of Non Reflexive relations?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

Def. : A relation 'R' on a set 'A' is called non- reflexive relation. If it is neither reflexive nor Irreflexive.

Representing relations in an $n\times n$ matrix

> Total no. relations: $2^{n^2}$
>
> Total no. of Reflexive Relations: $2^{n(n-1)}$
>
> Total no. of Irreflexive Relations: $2^{n(n-1)}$

So total no. of Non-reflexive relation according to the def. should be
= Total no. relations - (Total no. of Reflexive Relations + Total no. of Irreflexive   Relations)
$= 2^{n^2} - (2^{n(n-1)} + 2^{n(n-1)})$
$= 2^{n^2} - 2^{n(n-1) + 1}$

But I searched the internet and find total no. of Non-reflexive relation $= 2^{n^2} - 2^{n(n-1)}$

I didn't understand please help what's wrong?

Comment: Your internet source probably considers irreflexive relations to be "non-reflexive".

Answer (score 1):

Your calculations are correct. Can you provide the source of the answer you found ?

Comment: Here
http://s12.postimg.org/yk5u1goel/Capturefff.png
This is asked in Online TarGATE test 5